# ZF2 - Include (autoload) class/namespace for all modules

Tags: zend-framework2

How to load namespace for all modules (global autoload for whole application)

So far I need to add this to each module:

```
 public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            /* ... */
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    /* ... */
                    'MyNameSpace'        => __DIR__ . '/../../library/MyNameSpace',            
                ),

            ),
        );
    }
```

how can I implement this functionality in `application.config.php`? (i just want to load some base classes for whole application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the modules you need use the file /config/application.config.php
Add the list of your modules to the array under module key.

```
return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Pages',
        'ModuleName',
    ),
    // ..... rest of array
)
```

The function getAutoloaderConfig() and getConfig() are used to load the configuration of the module (module internal configuration).

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

autoload that path in your index.php, i.e.,

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ . '/../../library/MyNameSpace');
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
if(!class_exists($class)) {
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    require_once($class);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can (or should) do this in the `application.config.php` file.  The whole point behind modules in the ZF2 framework is to separate logic into reusable, independent bits of code.  As such, each module maintains and manages its own configuration, including autoloading, independent of the main application or other modules.  These settings can often be overridden with the `.global.php` and `.local.php` files of the main `autoload/` directory, but the autoloading should be left to each individual module.

If the modules you're trying to include are custom pieces of code that you have developed, then perhaps you might want to look at whether they are actually modules at all, or simply code that belongs in the Application module.

Comment: in zf2 you need to inform the application which module you are using. please check http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/modules.html#informing-the-application-about-our-new-module